# Laravel set locale in config/app.php right codes

Tags: laravel

Why is the locale set in `config/app.php` by just two characters instead of the full locale. For example: `'locale' => 'en'`, to set it to english but why not set it like this: `'locale' => 'en-GB'`,. If i set it like 'en' how can Laravel distinguish what dateformat is should use as there is a difference between en-US and en-GB dateformat?

Comment: Date format is up to you. Laravel doesn't do any formatting on dates; it'll come out as `2020-01-26 10:39:53` sort of standardized values.

Comment: Laravel only provides a basic translation system. It is up to you to change this behaviour, apart from the fact that it is quite easy to change this in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`.